# How to dynamically import scss in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3

In Vue2, require can be used to dynamically require('*****.scss'),
Can I achieve the same behavior in Vue3?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention your bundler. Vite is recommended for Vue3 and supports dynamic and glob imports: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import
https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

The author asked to **switch** between styles with the previous style removed.

Modified the default Vite's Hello World app to load SCSS with a button. You can find a project in my repository on GitHub here: https://github.com/silentmantra/scss-dynamic-import/blob/master/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

```
const styles = import.meta.glob('../dynamic*.scss', { query: '?inline' });
const styleElem = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(styleElem);

async function loadStyle(name) {
    const { default: style } = await styles[`../${name}.scss`]();
    styleElem.textContent = style;
}
```

```
        <button type="button" @click="loadStyle('dynamic')">Load SCSS 1 dynamically</button>
        <button type="button" @click="loadStyle('dynamic2')">Load SCSS 2 dynamically</button>
```

When build the Vite (Rollup) generates a JS chunks for each style:

[image]

You can checkout and run it

```
npm istall
npm run dev
```

[image]

Comment: Will the previously imported but unused scss that has been imported in this way be garbage collected?

Comment: @JavinYang made switching between styles. you can have any number of styles you want

Answer (score 0):

for dynamic file name, you can use that, thanks to Alexander Nenashev:

HTML:

```
<button style="border: 2px solid red" @click="loadStyle('style1')">Style 1</button>

<button style="border: 2px solid blue" @click="loadStyle('style2')">Style 2</button>
```

TS or JS:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
async function loadStyle(name: string) {
    await import(`./css/${name}.scss`);
}
</script>
```

Comment: i create two scss files inside src/css